How do I seamlessly transition between Lottie animations on Android?
I have this character animation that has different actions based on user gestures, each action is a separate Lottie animation. Currently when the user interacts with the animated character, it flashes before changing to the next animation like shown below. I want to make it transition seamlessly where it seems like it's just one smooth animation without it flashing.

This is the code for the view displaying the animation:
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.airbnb.lottie.compose.*
import com.lumen.tomo.R
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Composable
fun ChatView() {
    val initialAnimation = R.raw.cat_idle  // Initial animation resource ID
    val tapAnimation = R.raw.cat_headshake          // Tap specific animation resource ID
    val swipeAnimation = R.raw.cat_heart      // Swipe specific animation resource ID

    var animationRes by remember { mutableIntStateOf(initialAnimation) }
    val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(animationRes))
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()  // Remember a CoroutineScope tied to the Composable's lifecycle

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = composition,
        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        animationRes = tapAnimation
                        delay(3000)
                        animationRes = initialAnimation
                    }
                })
                detectDragGestures { _, _ ->
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        animationRes = swipeAnimation
                        delay(3000)
                        animationRes = initialAnimation
                    }
                }
            }
    )
}

